# ng repeat groups misordered

Tags: angularjs, group-by, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a group object already grouped by underscore, and the object is exactly how I like it to be ordered. But when I output the group object in page, the order is wrong.

see fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pbxaD/44/

```
$scope.groups = {"Day 1":[{"category":"Flight"},{"category":"Others"}],"Day 2":[{"category":"Train"}],"Day 3":[{"category":"Flight"}],"Day 18":[{"category":"Car"}],"undefined":[{"category":"Flight"}]};
```

the correct should be: Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, Day 18, undefined
but the output is becoming: Day 1, Day 18, Day 2, Day 3, undefined

Any suggestions?

Comment: you see, 'key' is string value, and your 'groups' is HashMap, so based on hashes of 'Day 1, Day 2, Day 3, Day 18, undefined', proper order is 'Day 1, Day 18, Day 2, Day 3, undefined'. only way is to write custom filter, split key value by space, sort by first part, take second part is exist, transfer to int, compare and sort

Comment: What is the angularjs version are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `angularjs` default behavior for the version 1.2 & 1.3. However, this behavior has been removed in angular 1.4.

I updated the link with angular 1.4 as external resources, It is working as you wanted

http://jsfiddle.net/pbxaD/48/

Answer (score 1):

Objects in javascript, unlike arrays, aren't ordered. If you want to keep the data structure as it is at the moment, your best bet is to write a custom filter as Dmitri Algazin commented. If you can handle the structure changing slightly, check the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pbxaD/47/

```
$scope.groups = [
    {
        day: "Day 1",
        categories:["Flight","Others"]
    },
    {
        day: "Day 2",
        categories: ["Train"]
    }, // etc
]
```

Answer (score 1):

By default javascript object key retrieve as ascending orders. in your case  for ordering its comparing two string. so as string comparison `'b'` obviously greater then `'ab'`. so in your case `'Day 18'` actually less then `'Day 2'`. that's why 'Day 18' comes before 'Day 2'. 
here is you can see string comparison specification [click here](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5)

you can use custom filters to change the orders.